# Calculate Ranked Probability Score

Tags: python

I have a csv-file that consists of all match outcome probabilities for soccer matches. Each math can be result in a win, draw or loss. I also included the actual outcome. In order to test how accurate my predictions are I want to use the Ranked Probability Score (RPS). Basically, the RPS compares the cumulative probability distributions of the predictions and the outcome:

> \$ RPS = \frac{1}{r-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^i p_j - \sum\limits_{j=1}^i e_j \right)^2, \$
>
> where \$r\$ is the number of potential outcomes, and \$p_j\$ and
>   \$e_j\$ are the forecasts and observed outcomes at position \$j\$.

For additional information, see the following [link](https://qmro.qmul.ac.uk/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/10783/Constantinou%20Solving%20the%20Problem%20of%20Inadequate%202012%20Accepted.pdf).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def RPS(predictions, observed):
   ncat = 3
   npred = len(predictions)
   RPS = np.zeros(npred)

   for x in range(0, npred):
      obsvec = np.zeros(ncat)
      obsvec[observed.iloc[x]-1] = 1
      cumulative = 0
      for i in range(1, ncat):
          cumulative = cumulative + (sum(predictions.iloc[x, 1:i]) - sum(obsvec[1:i])) ** 2
          RPS[x] = (1/(ncat-1)) * cumulative

    return RPS

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0)
predictions = df[['H', 'D', 'L']]
observed = df[['Outcome']]
RPS = RPS(predictions, observed)
```

The first argument (predictions) is a matrix with the predictions and the corresponding probabilities.  Each row is one prediction, laid out in the proper order (H, D, L), where each element is a probability and each row sum to 1. The second argument (observed) is a numeric vector that indicates which outcome that was actually observed (1, 2, 3)

Feel free to give any feedback!
Thank you

**Edit:**

For some reason I am not able to reproduce the results of Table 3 of the [link](https://qmro.qmul.ac.uk/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/10783/Constantinou%20Solving%20the%20Problem%20of%20Inadequate%202012%20Accepted.pdf). I use Table 1 as input for predictions and observed. Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit #2:**

Hereby the small sample of the paper:

```
predictions = {'H': [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.35, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.55],
               'D': [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.45, 0.1],
               'L': [0, 0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.35, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.05, 0.35]}

observed = {'Outcome': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: _"I am not able to reproduce the results of Table 3"_ If the code is not working correctly it is not ready for review.

Answer (score 0):

### Tidy up your math

```
cumulative = cumulative + (sum(predictions.iloc[x, 1:i]) - sum(obsvec[1:i])) ** 2
```

can be

```
cumulative += (sum(predictions.iloc[x, 1:i]) - sum(obsvec[1:i])) ** 2
```

and

```
RPS[x] = (1/(ncat-1)) * cumulative
```

should be

```
RPS[x] = cumulative / (ncat-1)
```

### Make a main method

This is a very small script, but still benefits from pulling your global code into a `main`.

### PEP8

By convention, method names (i.e. `RPS`) should be lowercase.

That's all I see for now.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the replies. In the end it was relatively simple. My code is based on R, matrices start with 1 in R. Python, however, starts with 0. Adjusting my original code with this insight (sorry..) I am able to reproduce the output. I also included the remarks of Reinderien.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def rps(predictions, observed):
   ncat = 3
   npred = len(predictions)
   rps = np.zeros(npred)

   for x in range(0, npred):
      obsvec = np.zeros(ncat)
      obsvec[observed.iloc[x]-1] = 1
      cumulative = 0
      for i in range(1, ncat):
         cumulative += (sum(predictions.iloc[x, 0:i]) - sum(obsvec[0:i])) ** 2
         rps[x] = cumulative / (ncat-1))

      return rps

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0)
predictions = df[['H', 'D', 'L']]
observed = df[['Outcome']]
rps = rps(predictions, observed)
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured out your issue, but - a few things. Your code in your answer is not properly indented. Also, it definitely doesn't run, because you wrote `RPS`, which no longer exists. Finally: if your code was broken in the first place, then this entire question is off-topic.